# Mercurial bitbucket authorization failed

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, hgrc

I changed my Bitbucket password based on 1Pass's watchtower recommendation. Ever since, I can't pull / push any of my repos, although I can login via a browser. I've tried both HTTP and SSH, and neither work.

Here is a sample output.

```
hg pull --debug https://caliChander@bitbucket.org/caliChander/cs1
using https://bitbucket.org/caliChander/cs1
http auth: user caliChander, password not set
sending capabilities command
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
http auth: user caliChander, password *******************************
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
http auth: user caliChander, password *******************************
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
http auth: user caliChander, password *******************************
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
http auth: user caliChander, password *******************************
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
http auth: user caliChander, password *******************************
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
http auth: user caliChander, password *******************************
using auth.bitbucket.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
abort: authorization failed
```

I'm curious as to why it says "password not set" when my `~/.hgrc` looks something like this:

```
[ui]
username = First Last <some.email@random.com>
[auth]
bitbucket.prefix = bitbucket.org
bitbucket.username = caliChander
bitbucket.password = some_very_long_password_here
bitbucket.schemes = http https
[web]
cacerts = /etc/hg-dummy-cert.pem
```

My gut feeling is that certain characters aren't allowed in the password field? This was randomly generated via 1Pass. Is this so?

Just in case it's needed, the `.hg/hgrc` in the `cs1` repo looks like this:

`[paths]
default = https://caliChander@bitbucket.org/caliChander/cs1`

I'm on OS X Mavericks. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious as to why it says "password not set"

Because URL may contain both username and password, your `https://caliChander@bitbucket.org/` have only username part

[ui] section is irrelevant in auth-stage (it's just informative data, used for defining userdata, shown in log for local commits), only username-password from [auth] used for authentication. You can temporary disable password in hgrc and enter it by hand

Comment: Yup, manually entering the password works.
Any clue why the auth section in the `~/.hgrc` that contains the password is being ignored?

Comment: @ChanderRamesh - it will not be ignored if you'll use **correct prefix** (without username) - *any* leading part of your real URL doesn't match prefix `bitbucket.org`. Username was catched from URL, password not used due to prefix-mismatch